# SQL Server 2019 RC in Production?

Tags: sql-server

I have a MS SQL Server 2008R2 running our two main databases.
I have a few problems with MS SQL Server 2008R2, and would like to upgrade ASAP.

i did however not get the funds to buy a 2017, only for a 2019 when it comes out.

So I have the following options:

1) 2008R2-->2017(eval version)-->2019 (as soon as it is out)

2) 2008R2-->2019RC-->2019 full (as soon as it is out)

3) Stay on 2008R2 until 2019 is out.

I think that 1 is not allowed licencing-wise? Would 2 be ok? How big would the risk be of running the 2019RC?

Thank you
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

Sever Fault cannot answer licensing questions. Contact the vendor, in this case Microsoft or your reseller.

As of September 2019, the [release notes for SQL Server 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/sql-server-ver15-release-notes) explain it is in preview. With no support available, there is considerable risk should it not work for you in production.

> ### SQL Server 2019 release candidate (RC)
>
> SQL Server 2019 RC is the latest public release of SQL Server 2019.
>
> SQL Server 2019 RC is available only as Evaluation Edition. No other
>   editions are available.
>
> Complete details about support and licensing for release candidate
>   software are in license_Eval.rtf with your installation media.
>
> ### Support
>
> SQL Server 2019 RC is preview software. It is not publicly supported
>   for operations. Customers who are in the [SQL Early Adopter
>   Program](http://aka.ms/sqleap), may have support to run SQL Server 2019 RC by special
>   agreement, in consultation with Microsoft.

Regarding upgrade path:

> While [side-by-side or in-place upgrade] from SQL Server 2008 and 2008
>   R2 is not blocked, there are no commonly supported Windows Operating
>   system versions between them and SQL Server 2019.

One upgrade strategy would be to build new test and production hosts on the latest Windows Server, 2019 if possible. This removes the need to upgrade Windows in place. If desired, run SQL 2019 previews in the test environment to understand it in advance of release.